# Spark dataset. Group struct column in array

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, grouping

I have two json files that I want to combine.

They look like this:

Elements:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "style": {
      "availableColors": [1,3,5,8]
      "material" : "Iron"
       .
       .
       .
      }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Colors:

```
{
  "colorId" : 1,
  "definition": {
      "R": 13,
      "G" : 23,
      "B" : 4
      }
   "tags": ["...", "..."]
  .
  .
  .
}
```

I've converted each in a DF and I am joining them as follows:

```
val joined = elemDF.join(colorDF, $"style.id".cast("string").contains($"colorId"))
```

But in that case each id has as many entries as colorIds.

How can I "group" the colors inside an array, so in the end it would be like adding an array of color structs to each element?

Maybe using a udf instead of joining the dataframes?

I would like to avoid using classes to represent the rows, as the json can have many fields and levels which I should not care at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got a solution. I'll add it in case anyone has the same problem.

```
def toColumns(colNames: Array[String]) = {
  colNames.map(x => col(x))
}

val joined = elemDF.join(colorDF, $"style.id".cast("string").contains($"colorId"))
                   .withColumn("color", 
                            struct(toColumns(colorDF.schema.fieldNames): _*)



joined.groupBy(toColumns(elemDF.schema.fieldNames): _*)
      .agg(collect_list($"color").as("colors"))
```